# If $ f \bigl ( x - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f ( - x ) + \bigl ( f ( y ) - 2 x \bigr ) \cdot f ( - y ) $ what is $ f ( x ) $

Tags: functional-equations

> Determine all functions $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that
> $$ f \bigl ( x - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f ( - x ) + \bigl ( f ( y ) - 2 x \bigr ) \cdot f ( - y ) $$
> for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $.

It's easy to see that $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $ is a function satisfying the above equation. Thus I thought it would be wise to first prove that $ f $ is an even function. The best I did is to conclude that $ f \bigl ( - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f \bigl ( - f ( - y ) \bigr ) $. Then I tried to prove that $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $ but failed.

Comment: The functional equation looks cleaner if we replace $f$ by $g : s \mapsto f(-s)$, and $x$ by $t+f(y)/2$.

Comment: This functional equation has appeared on AOPS [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1201850p5911923) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1518587p9059228). Each post has received a different elegant answer by the user [pco](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/user/29428). I posted an answer based on the one in the first link above.

Answer (score 3):

It's straightforward to verify that $ f ( x ) = 0 $ and $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 + a $ for any constant $ a \in \mathbb R $ satisfy
$$ f \bigl ( x - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f ( - x ) + \bigl ( f ( y ) - 2 x \bigr ) f ( - y ) \tag 0 \label 0 $$
for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $. We show that these are the only solutions. For this, first note that for any $ y , z \in \mathbb R $ if we have $ f ( y ) = f ( z ) $ then we also have $ f ( - y ) = f ( - z ) $, as can be seen by choosing $ x $ in \eqref{0} such that $ f ( y ) \ne 2 x $. For example, one can set $ x = \frac { f ( y ) - 1 } 2 $ in \eqref{0} to get
$$ f ( - y ) = f \left ( - \frac { 1 + f ( y ) } 2 \right ) - f \left ( \frac { 1 - f ( y ) } 2 \right ) $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R $, which clearly has the desired property as a consequence. Letting $ a = f ( 0 ) $ and putting $ x = 0 $ in \eqref{0} we get
$$ f \bigl ( - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f ( y ) f ( - y ) + a \tag 1 \label 1 $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R $. Substituting $ - y $ for $ y $ in \eqref{1} and comparing to \eqref{1} itself, we have $ f \bigl ( - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f \bigl ( - f ( - y ) \bigr ) $, and thus
$$ f \bigl ( f ( y ) \bigr ) = f \bigl ( f ( - y ) \bigr ) \tag 2 \label 2 $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R $. Setting $ y = 0 $ in \eqref{0}, we get
$$ f ( x - a ) = f ( - x ) + a ( a - 2 x ) \tag 3 \label 3 $$
for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Now, substituting $ - f ( y ) $ for $ x $ in \eqref{3} we have
$$ f \bigl ( - f ( y ) - a \bigr ) = f \bigl ( f ( y ) \bigr ) + a \bigl ( a + 2 f ( y ) \bigr ) \text , $$
while setting $ x = - a $ in \eqref{0} gives
$$ f \bigl ( - a - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f \bigl ( a \bigr ) + \bigl ( f ( y ) + 2 a \bigr ) f ( - y ) $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R $. Comparing the last couple of equations, we get
$$ f \bigl ( f ( y ) \bigr ) = 2 a \bigl ( f ( - y ) - f ( y ) \bigr ) + f ( y ) f ( - y ) + f ( a ) - a ^ 2 \tag 4 \label 4 $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R $. Substituting $ - y $ for $ y $ in \eqref{4} and comparing to \eqref{4} itself, we get $ a \bigl ( f ( - y ) - f ( y ) \bigr ) = 0 $ for all $ y \in \mathbb R $, using \eqref{2}. Now, if for some $ y \in \mathbb R $ we had $ f ( - y ) \ne f ( y ) $, then we would have $ a = 0 $, which then contradicts \eqref{3}. Therefore, we must have
$$ f ( - y ) = f ( y ) $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R $, which helps us rewrite \eqref{0} as
$$ f \bigl ( x - f ( y ) \bigr ) = f ( x ) + \bigl ( f ( y ) - 2 x \bigr ) f ( y ) \text , \tag 5 \label 5 $$
and \eqref{1} as
$$ f \bigl ( f ( y ) \bigr ) = f ( y ) ^ 2 + a \text . \tag 6 \label 6 $$
Substituting $ f ( x ) $ for $ x $ in \eqref{5} and using \eqref{6}, we get
$$ f \bigl ( f ( x ) - f ( y ) \bigr ) = \bigl ( f ( x ) - f ( y ) \bigr ) ^ 2 + a \tag 7 \label 7 $$
for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $. Now, if there is some $ b \in \mathbb R $ with $ f ( b ) \ne 0 $, substituting $ \frac { x + f ( b ) ^ 2 } { 2 f ( b ) } $ for $ x $ and $ b $ for $ y $ in \eqref{5} we get
$$ f \left ( \frac { x + f ( b ) ^ 2 } { 2 f ( b ) } \right ) - f \left ( \frac { x - f ( b ) ^ 2 } { 2 f ( b ) } \right ) = x \text , $$
which then substituting $ \frac { x + f ( b ) ^ 2 } { 2 f ( b ) } $ for $ x $ and $ \frac { x - f ( b ) ^ 2 } { 2 f ( b ) } $ for $ y $ in \eqref{7}, gives us $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 + a $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Therefore, the function $ f $ must be of this form, unless it is the constant zero function.

Comment: It took me a while to follow why $f(y)=f(z)$ implies $f(-y)=f(-z)$. Maybe you could write that part out.

Comment: @aschepler I added a brief explanation in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

This is a loose derivation.

Let $x = 0$, to have:
$$
f(-f(y))=f(0)+f(y)\cdot f(-y)
$$
Let $ y = -y$:
$$
f(-f(-y))=f(0)+f(-y)\cdot f(y)
$$
So $f(-(f(y)) = f(-f(-y))$, I think this is sufficient to conclude that $f$ is even, by apply $f^{-1}$ on both sides and multiply $-1$.

Now with $f$ even,
$$
f(-f(y))=f(0)+f(y)\cdot f(y)
$$
Let $f(y) = x$, we have:
$$
f(-x)=f(x)=f(0)+x^2
$$

You can **not** determine what $f(0)$ is.

Comment: Why do you think an inverse $f^{-1}$ exists? Are you aware that $y=-y$ implies $y=0$?

Comment: @flawr That's why I said it's loose :-) By $y = -y$ what I meant is substitute $y$ by $-y$.

Comment: Oh now I see what you did, perhaps you should switch the sign in the most rigth hand term of the second equation too (just for readability).

Comment: @flawr, I see, updated.